# How do I map a nested index to the return result of a method?

Tags: tire

Suppose I have a definition as such (simplified for brevity)

```
class Charlie
  include Mongoid::Document

  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks

  field :line1, type:String
  field :line2, type:String

  embedded_in :bravo

  def calculated_field
    ["From", "Charlie"]
  end
end

class Bravo
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks

  store_in collection: "test123", database: "user_sourced_data"

  embeds_one :charlie, :autobuild => true

  field :first_name, type:String
  field :last_name, type:String

  mapping do
    indexes :first_name
    indexes :last_name
    indexes :outer_field, :as => 'calculated_field'
    indexes :charlie do
      indexes :line1
      indexes :line2
      indexes :embedded_field, :as =>'calculated_field'
    end
  end

  def calculated_field
    ["This", "is", "from", "Bravo"]
  end
end
```

The first "outer_field" property is correctly returned in Elastic Search with the array of values, however, the "embedded_field" is never populated in Elastic Search

Here is the following JSON output from ES:

```
{
_index: bravos
_type: bravo
_id: 54821f2a36b8d92713000001
_score: 0.30685282
_source: {
charlie: {
_id: 54821f2d36b8d92713000002,
line1: "ABC",
line2: "DEF"
}
first_name: "Johnny",
last_name: "Walker",
my_other_field: [
"This",
"is",
"from",
"Bravo"
]
}
}
```

What do I need to modify in order to have it return the results of the "calculated_field" property in the embedded class (rather than the outer class)

EDIT: the to_indexed_json output of the object instance is as thus:

```
  {
   "charlie"   =>   {  
      "_id"      =>"54821f2d36b8d92713000002",
      "line1"      =>"ABC",
      "line2"      =>"DEF"
   },
   "first_name"   =>"Whiskey",
   "last_name"   =>"Tango",
   "my_other_field"   =>   [  "This", "is", "from", "Bravo" ]
   }
```